# Just deployed Office 2010 using an image and it's showing 'Product Activation Failed', help!

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

I've just imaged over 200 PCs with Windows 7 and Office 2010, Office 2010 is showing a red banner at the top with 'Product Activation Failed'. Can I fix this using Group Policy or a script?

Thanks
Sean

Comment: More info about the deploy method and licensing method will assist in getting answers.

Answer (score 3):

You're a bit lacking on the details but it sounds like you just need to properly activate them. You have 2 simple options:

You can install a KMS server, which will become discoverable by the devices and so they should just start activating. If you need to force an activation at login, you can run this command via a script

> C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14\ospp.vbs" /act

Your other option is to use [Microsoft's Volume Activation Management Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ec7156d2-2864-49ee-bfcb-777b898ad582&displaylang=en) to connect to the computers, install a MAK product key, and activate all of them.

Comment: +1 VAMT is great if you have MAK activation